# When are Green's functions causal convolution kernels

Tags: differential-equations, differential-operators, green-function

Let $L$ be a linear differential operarator acting on distributions over $\mathbb{R}$ and $G(t, s)$ be a Green's function, i.e., a solution to $LG(t, s) =\delta(t-s)$.

- $G$ is said to be **causal** if $G(t, s)=0$ for $s>t$.
- $G$ is said to be a **convolution kernel** if there exists a function, $g$,  such that $G(t,s)=g(t-s)$.

> **Question:** Are there necessary and sufficient conditions for $L$ to have a Green's function that is a causal convolution kernel?

Comment: You're of course correct. I had in mind an existence question. The language has been updated to reflect this.

Comment: no initial condition?